# jssor slider not compatible with Theia Sticky sidebar?

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am using the jssor slider on a website I am making and at that same website I am also using Theia Sticky sidebar ( http://liviucmg.com/theia-sticky-sidebar/ ). 
Although the slider works and also the sticky sidebar there is a small bug which is only present if the slider and the sticky sidebar are used on the same page.
I notice when I scroll to the bottom of my page, some elements of the sidebar start moving behind eachother. 
This issue is fixed if I remove the u="slides" from the html. But obviously that is not a solution as than the slider no longer works.

So, I have been going through the scripts and found 2 lines in jssor.slider.js:

```
Line 2733: var _SlidesContainer = $Jssor$.$FindChild(elmt, "slides", _UISearchNoDeep); 
Line 3639: _SlidesContainer = $Jssor$.$FindChild(elmt, "slides", false);
```

Of course "slides" is also present in my html:

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 530px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;"> 
   <!-- BEGIN: PAGE_ROW --> 
      <div> 
         <div><a u="image" href="{PAGE_ROW_URL}"><img src="{PAGE_ROW_MYSITE_LARGE_PAVATAR}" width="530" height="300" title="{PAGE_ROW_CATDESC}" /></a></div> 
         <div u="thumb"> 
              <img class="i" src="{PAGE_ROW_MYSITE_THUMB_PAVATAR}"> 
                  <div class="t">{PAGE_ROW_SHORTTITLE}</div> 
                  <div class="c"><a href="{PAGE_ROW_CATURL}">{PAGE_ROW_CATTITLE}</a></div> 
         </div> 
      </div> 
  <!-- END: PAGE_ROW --> 
</div>
```

So, I checked the theia-sticky-sidebar.js to see if any values from lines 2733 and 3639 match, which could cause a conflict, but as far as I can tell there is nothing which is the same causing a conflict. So, I decided to post here and see if you have maybe an idea how I can solve this?

The sticky sidebar works without issues on pages of the website where the slider is not used.

Comment: Can I have the url of your page? or you can send me via email. jssor@live.com

Comment: The website is only running locally atm as I am still working on it. Next week I will upload a version and than you can take a look at the issue yourself.
I will sent you the link to your email. Thank you very much for the support!